# Multiple parameters for trackPageView

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

Under Track Events I want to combine View Category, and View Item.
There is no documentation for combinations, so do I write:

```
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"category" : "INSERT_CATEGORY"}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM"}]);
```

Or do I write:

```
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"category" : "INSERT_CATEGORY"}, {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM"}]);
```

I assume the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some quick testing, and I can see, that the only way I can pass the information through to SFMC, is by having the code split across multiple lines. Hence this being the right solution:

```
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"category" : "INSERT_CATEGORY"}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM"}]);
```